# ReadWrite locks in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, reentrantreadwritelock

While a write lock is being held, Read lock can be acquired. But not vice versa. What is the rationale for this design choice.

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("read to write test");
        ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
        
        lock.writeLock().lock();
        lock.readLock().lock();
        
        System.out.println("Read locks can be acquired after  Write locks are acquired as well.");
    }
```

**Output of above code:**

```
read to write test
Read locks can be acquired after  Write locks are acquired as well.
```

Vice versa doesn't work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


        ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();


        lock.readLock().lock();
        
        System.out.println("Read lock is  acquired");
        System.out.print("Trying to get write lock. ");

        boolean  writeLockAcquired =  lock.writeLock().tryLock(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if (! writeLockAcquired){
            System.out.println("Even after 120 seconds, we  couldn't get write lock");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("We could get write lock.");
        }
        
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
Read lock is  acquired
Trying to get write lock. Even after 120 seconds, we  couldn't get write lock
```

Can some one point to snippets in Java open source projects to look at practical usage of Read Write locks. I understand that there are a lot of Java open source projects like ElasticSearch / Hadoop / Spark etc.

Comment: What's your best guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While a write lock is being held, Read lock can be acquired.

Locking is to protect against access by concurrent threads.

A read-write lock allows multiple concurrent readers OR a single writer thread.

If a thread owns the write lock, it already has exclusive access, so there's no harm in granting it read access.  It will not conflict with itself.

If a thread owns the read lock, there is no guarantee it has exclusive access, so granting the write lock is disallowed.  There is no benefit in special-casing the 'single thread wanting both locks' situation.

In other systems, the lock modes are referred to as 'exclusive' (= write) and 'shared' (= read) modes. Considering those terms might help clarify the situation.

There is further rationale in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html) for the reentrant read-write lock:

> Additionally, a writer can acquire the read lock, but not vice-versa.
> Among other applications, reentrancy can be useful when write locks
> are held during calls or callbacks to methods that perform reads under
> read locks. If a reader tries to acquire the write lock it will never
> succeed.

Comment: In other words, the behavior I see is because I am using the same main thread ? If we use different threads, when one of them is writing, other threads can't access the read lock ?

Comment: That's correct.  And the rationale for that is - the data protected by the lock are being written, so may be inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

Allowing a read lock to be upgraded to a write lock would be a source of deadlocks:

- Thread A takes a read lock (now no one can take a write lock)
- Thread B takes a read lock
- Thread A decides to upgrade to a write lock -- blocks
- Thread B decides to upgrade to a write lock -- deadlock

The correct way to do this (when you are doing an operation which may need a write lock, but usually doesn't) is to retry it:

- Thread A takes a read lock
- Thread B takes a read lock
- Thread A decides it needs a write lock
- Thread A drops the read lock
- Thread A tries to take the write lock -- blocks because B currently holds the read lock
- Thread B decides it needs a write lock
- Thread B drops the read lock
- Thread A gets the write lock
- Thread B tries to take the write lock and blocks
- Thread A finishes its work and releases the lock
- Thread B takes the write lock